# Unable to display background image using javascript on qualtrics

Tags: javascript, background-image

For starters, I have absolute no knowledge with javascript. I am trying to display a background image extracted from a url address on just a page of the questionnaire on qualtrics with the following codes:-

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function()
{
    <div id="divtest">Hello</div>
    <img id="imgtest" />
    <img id="imgreal" src="http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/2-flower-wallpaper.jpg" />

    var string = 'http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/01-2014/2-flower-wallpaper.jpg';
    document.getElementById("divtest").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + string + "')";
    document.getElementById("imgtest").src = string;


});
```

But I got the following error message:-

*Invalid JavaScript! You cannot save until you fix all errors: Unexpected token <*

How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: Euh, copy paste error? Else just remove the <div> and <img> tags from your javascript, since you just want to edit the style. You can't mix html and javascript in this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add HTML directly in javascript code, you have to create into body section of your page, or if you need to create elements via code you have to use createElement

```
var _div = document.createElement('div');
_div.id = 'divtest';
_div.innerHTML = 'Hello';
_div.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + string + "')";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(_div); // to place as child of body
```

or

```
document.getElementById('[ID of parent element]').appendChild(_div); // to place as child of other element.
```